# I've tried every line break for createTextNode but I can't make one

Tags: javascript

`/n` doesn't work on my code as it doesn't print out a line break. Please help!

`</br>` doesn't work

```
<script> 
        var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
        x.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
        document.body.appendChild(x);

        var y = document.createElement("TR");
        y.setAttribute("id", "myTr");
        document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(y);

        var z = document.createElement("TD");

        var column = 1
        for(row = 1; row < 13; row++){
            var product = column*row;
            if(column != 13){
                var t = document.createTextNode(product + " ")
                if(row == 12){
                    column += 1
                    var t = document.createTextNode(product + " \u000a" + column)
                    row = 1;
                }
            }
            else if(column == 13){
                break
            }
            z.appendChild(t);
            document.getElementById("myTr").appendChild(z);
        }
    </script>
```

This is what I get:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 24 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 36 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 48 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 510 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 612 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 66 72 714 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70 77 84 816 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80 88 96 918 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90 99 108 1020 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120 1122 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 110 121 132 1224 36 48 60 72 84 96 108 120 132 144 13

Comment: What's the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are making a table with a single table row.
If you want it to be in multiple rows, you need multiple `tr`.

This is what you currently have.

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr id="myTr">1\n 2\n 3\n</tr>
</table>
```

This is what you seem to want.

```html
<table id="myTable">
   <tr id="myTr">1 2 3 4</tr>
   <tr>3 4 5 6</tr>
</table>
```

You can try the studying the following code as an example

This will create a table with the numbers 1 - 50 with 5 rows and 10 columns.

I do not recommend using `\t` for separation or visual type of stuff. You should consider using CSS for styling spacing and whatnot.

```js
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute("id", "myTable");

const ROWS = 5;
const COLUMNS = 10;

var product = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    // Create the rows element
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
        // Put the "product" in the row. \t is the tab seperator, for easy view.
        row.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product+"\t"));
        product += 1;
    }

    // Append the row with the data in the table.
    table.appendChild(row);
}

// Append the table to the body element to view.
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: This actually creates a table with 5 rows and **1** column, because there are no `td` elements. In `for (var j=0; j < COLUMNS ...)` it should be creating a _table-data_ element `document.createElement("td")`, create a text node _in_ that `td` element, and append _that whole thing_ to the `tr` row